# Japanese Regex for Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

** Question:** How do I allow only numbers in japanese(Hiragana/Katagana)

**Use case:** I want to take "number" field (My input should only accept numbers from English and Japanese)

I've written the following sample snippet:

```js
// The goal of this demo is to demonstrate the RegEx patterns for English and Japanese Chracters

var english = "09c12";
var japanese =  "０１２３あb";


console.log("-----English Test---")
console.log(english.replace(/[^0-9\/]/gi, ''));
console.log("--------------------")


console.log("-----japanese Test---")
console.log(japanese.replace(/[^0-9\/]/gi, ''));
console.log("--------------------")
```

**Issue:**
This is not working for Japanese. Please enlighten me.

I am assuming Japanese characters have different ASCII/Unicode values?

Please help me fix the code. I want to just make sure the user enters the numbers.

Thanks

Comment: `０１２３あsd２` ... what are these numbers exactly?  I think in kanji the numbers for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean would all look about the same, and not this, which appears to be a mixture of Arabic and characters.  In any case, you're probably going to have to use unicode literals here.  Update your question and someone can hopefully answer.

Comment: It's `0123ab` in hiragana. Updated this in question @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 9):

Your Japanese digits are not simple ASCII digits, they are unicode fullwidth characters, (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff10/index.htm)

the regex syntax in javascript doesn't have unicode classes, so you'll have to select for them by manually specifying the unicode range.

```js
console.log("０１２３あb".replace(/[\uff10-\uff19]/g, "_"));
console.log("０１２３あb".replace(/[^\uff10-\uff19]/g, "_"));
console.log(String.fromCharCode(...[...Array(10)].map((x, i) => 0xff10 + i))
);
```

Comment: Hey @Jimmy thanks so much for answering. One question, I just want to accept input as "numbers" in Japanese (Hiragana/Katakana) would this regEx work fine? Please let me know.

Comment: yes `'\uff10'` -> `"０"`, `'\uff19'` -> `"９"`, so this range only includes the 10 fullwidth numerical digits.

Comment: But your regex is Removing numbers not preserving them. I want to preserve ONLY numbers and remove everything else :-(

https://jsfiddle.net/rdabbir/0t1811pp/3/ 

@Jimmy thanks for your help

Comment: Add a caret `[^\uff10-\uff19]`. There's nothing special about unicode in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Is this useful for you?

```js
var english = "09c12";
var japanese = "０１２３あsd２";


console.log("-----English Test---")
console.log(english.replace(/[^0-9\/]/gi, ''));
console.log("--------------------")


console.log("-----japanese Test---")
console.log(japanese.replace(/[^０-９]/g, ''));
console.log("--------------------")
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mp1fzsLp/1/)

Comment: cool! it never occurred to me to put Unicode directly in the regex.

Comment: @Jimmy Thank you. I thought that may can use double-byte character for this. This was new try for me.